# What is the function of include guard in .cpp (not in .h)?

Tags: c++

Ok, may be this question have answer already but I don't know what keyword to search (most of my searched results are about include guard in `.h` only, but not in `.cpp`)

Sometimes I saw in `cpp` each #`include` line have a extra include guard (sometimes even the included `.h` already have the own include guard) like this:
SomeClass.cpp

```
#ifndef__A__
#include A.h
#endif
#ifndef__B__
#include B.h
#endif
#ifndef__C__
#include C.h
#endif
```

instead of

SomeClass.cpp

```
#include A.h
#include B.h
#include C.h
```

, what is the function of this include guard?

Comment: They are called external include guards, generally made popular by the Large Scale C++ Software Design book.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110436/cleaning-up-legacy-code-header-spaghetti/110608#110608

Answer (score 2):

The practice of using include guards in .cpp files was recommended by John Lakos in his book [Large-Scale C++ Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620). I don't know whether any one before him had recommended the practice.

Say you have

A.h:

```
#ifndef __A__
#define __A__

#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

// ...
// ...
// ...

#endif
```

B.h:

```
#ifndef __B__
#define __B__

// ...
// ...
// ...

#endif
```

C.h:

```
#ifndef __C__
#define __C__

// ...
// ...
// ...

#endif
```

SomeClass.cpp:

```
#ifndef __A__
#include "A.h"
#endif

#ifndef __B__
#include "B.h"
#endif

#ifndef __C__
#include "C.h"
#endif
```

When SomeClass.cpp is compiled, the contents of A.h is included. As a by-product of including the contents of A.h, the contents of B.h and C.h are also included. Also, the pre-processor macros `__A__`, `__B__` and `__C__` are defined. When the line

```
#ifndef __B__
```

is processed, since `__B__` is already defined, the next line is skipped.

If SomeClass.cpp had just:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
```

the file B.h has to be opened and processed. The contents of the file will not be included again due to the include guards but the file has to be opened and closed.

By using the first strategy, you avoid the cost of of opening and closing B.h and C.h. For large scale C++ project, John Lakos asserts, the cost is too much. Hence, the recommendation of using include guards even in .cpp files.

Comment: Note that some modern compilers (such as GCC) remember header guards, which makes this technique redundant.

Answer (score 1):

It means don't even check the content of header file if the file is already included (`symbol_specific_to_header` is defined).

In ancient time when opening a file and **checking whether contents are already included** in header itself was costly (Cost of opening, reading and closing the header was very high) this trick was used to reduce the compile time.

But on modern systems this trick is not required. Though this doesn't cause any harm except the code is repeated and adding cluttering, this would work. Althout adding hashguards in include files is recommended.

This is how the header file looks and are included.

**New style:**

```
/* A.h */
#pragma once
...
```

or

```
/* A.h */
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
...
#endif
```

usage:

```
#include "A.h"
```

Or precompiled headers are used.

**Old style**

The ancient style as mentioned by you:

```
/* A.h */
#define A_H
...
```

usage:

```
#ifndef A_H
#include "A.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Yip it's the cost of opening the file.

Comment: but doesn't it seem unnecessary to have B.h and C.h at all? imho they should be removed

Comment: @tejashs Sorry I could not understand your concern. Can you please elaborate. `b.h` and `c.h` are independent files just like `a.h` and may bve completely orthogonal.

Comment: if we know that b.h and c.h are included in a.h we dont need to include them in the cpp file at all. only a.h should suffice

Comment: @tejashs How do you know that `b.h` and `c.h` are included in `a.h`? I might have missed. Is it written in question somewhere or is implied? I read the question again but no luck.

Comment: I thought it was implied

Comment: @tejashs No I don't see it is implied by any of the sentence or code example.

Answer (score 0):

It's to protect against including the same header twice.

A.h might look something like this

```
#define __A__
#include B.h
```

Without the guards, B.h would be included twice, which could cause errors.  So the #ifndef lines in the cpp is just protecting itself from headers including other headers.